# How can I use !expr for inline coding in qarto with python?

Tags: date, yaml, expr

In my YAML Header I try this for date:

```
date: "`!expr format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
date-format: dddd, D MMM YYYY
lang: de
```

But if I render I receive an error message:

```
Invalid Date
```

Did I use !expr in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the Quarto documentation:

```
date: today
```

will help in the specific language format.